# Maintain order of elements in event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, twitter-bootstrap

I have a series of radio-style button groups (made using Bootstrap), each of them is labelled a letter. Depending on the clicked button, the associated letter should be placed within either 'Yes' or 'No' rows. For example, clicking `Yes` button associated with label `A` should make `A` appears in 'Yes' row. Here is a fiddle to illustrate the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/A38Ap/

I should point out that the 'click' event callback is fired *before* the `.active` class is added to the clicked button in Bootstrap.

An additional requirement is that the order of letters in 'Yes' and 'No' row should respect the order of button groups shown above. For example, if 'Yes' is clicked for both `C` and `A`, *no matter in which order they are clicked*, `C` should always appear before `A` in the 'Yes' row, because `C` group is in front of `A` group (left-to-right).

The fiddle above does NOT satisfy this additional requirement, and I struggle to think of an efficient way to do it. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each button - in the onclick event of the buttons, just toggle the 'active' class on the button which is clicked.

At the end of the end loop through all the buttons to decide which have been clicked, and display the status accordingly. Looping at the end, will give you the advantage of knowing the state of all the buttons before you are about to print the state of the buttons. As you printing in the last step you can maintain your order as you need.